# ASP.NET MVC 2 - Implementing custom Metadata and Validator Providers

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2, metadata, ironruby, provider

With the [preview 2 release of ASP.NET MVC 2](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/10/01/asp.net-mvc-preview-2-released.aspx), we now have base classes to implement our own custom providers for metadata and validation. Specifically, with [ModelMetadataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadataprovider(VS.100).aspx) and [ModelValidatorProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelvalidatorprovider(VS.100).aspx).

There isn't a lot of documentation on these yet (just released yesterday as a **preview**, so I'm neither surprised nor disappointed).

Has anyone gotten custom implementations of either of these working? A very simple example (metadata and validator for just "Required") would be great!

Perhaps a lot of people have the same idea, but I'd like to use IronRuby to inject the metadata, and I'm looking for any example to get started.

Thanks!

***Edit***: Sounds like [Brad Wilson](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/about.html) (of [xUnit.net](http://www.codeplex.com/xunit) fame) has some blog posts coming for this exact thing! If he doesn't answer here, I'll create an answer with links when those posts are ready.

***Edit2***: Sankarsan Bose over at [CodingNDesign](http://codingndesign.com/) also has [posts on the subject](http://codingndesign.com/blog/?tag=asp-net-mvc-2-0). (ModelValidator at the moment). Including here for future reference.